# How to check winner in Tic Tac Toe as well as how to not let the both players to enter at the same position?

Tags: c++

I want to do 2 things with my code now.
1) check the winner
2) not let both players to enter at the same position
eg.if, player1 has already entered value at board[0][0]='X', and player2 again enters board[0][0]='0', how can i not let the player again to enter at board[0][0]?

likewise, how do i check the winner?

i have tried to check the winner by checking

```
if(board[0][0]==board[0][1]==board[0][2]
```

then the winner is player1.(after the player1 pressed his input)

But,  it didn't work.

I want to be honest that I still didn't get logic for my next question i.e how to not let both players to enter at the same position?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int choice;


char board[3][3]={{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};


void display_board()
{
system("cls");
    cout<<"..............................................Tick Cross Game by Pakistani coder........................................"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\tPlayer1[X]\n\t\t\t\t\tPlayer2[0]\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t__"<<board[0][0]<<"___ __"<<board[0][1]<<"___ __"<<board[0][2]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t__"<<board[1][0]<<"___ __"<<board[1][1]<<"___ __"<<board[1][2]<<"\n";

    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t     |     |     \n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t___"<<board[2][0]<<"__ __"<<board[2][1]<<"___ __"<<board[2][2]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t     |     |     \n";
   /// cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t     |     |     \n";

}
void player_turn()
{

        cout<<"\n\tPlayer1[X] turn:";
    cin>>choice;


    switch(choice)
    {

    case 1:
        board[0][0]='X';
        break;

    case 2:
        board[0][1]='X';
        break;

    case 3:
        board[0][2]='X';
        break;

    case 4:
        board[1][0]='X';
        break;

           case 5:
        board[1][1]='X';
        break;

           case 6:
        board[1][2]='X';
        break;

           case 7:
        board[2][0]='X';
        break;

           case 8:
        board[2][1]='X';
        break;

           case 9:
        board[2][2]='X';
        break;
        default:

        cout<<"invalid choice";
        break;
        ///value will go there but need to display the board also

    }
    display_board();
    //checkwin();
    cout<<"player 2 turn\n";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice)
    {


    case 1:
        board[0][0]='0';
        break;



    case 2:
        board[0][1]='0';
        break;

    case 3:
        board[0][2]='0';
        break;

    case 4:
        board[1][0]='0';
        break;

           case 5:
        board[1][1]='0';
        break;

           case 6:
        board[1][2]='0';
        break;

           case 7:
        board[2][0]='0';
        break;

           case 8:
        board[2][1]='0';
        break;

           case 9:
        board[2][2]='0';
        break;
        default:

        cout<<"invalid choice";
        break;
    }

    display_board();
}

int main()
{
   /*for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {

       for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
       {

           cout<<board[i][j];
       }
   }*/
   while(1)
   {

    display_board();
player_turn();


    display_board();
    }
}
```

expected output:
whenever both players enter at the same array location board[0][0], then it should show "invalid choice" for the second player who inserted in that position.

likewise, whenever the winning condition of tictactoe occurs. i.e if 
1) the consecutive 3 rows have the same value
2)consecutive 3 cols have the same value
3)diagonal elements have the same value(3)

Comment: add a check before that to see that the is no value there, init the matrix too -1 or any other number that you don't use if it "free" do the insert otherwise do the  "invalid choice"

Comment: The expression `board[0][0]==board[0][1]==board[0][2]` is equal to `(board[0][0]==board[0][1])==board[0][2]`. That is, you compare the bool result of the first comparison with `board[0][2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(board[0][0]==board[0][1]==board[0][2]
```

should be

```
if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][1] == board[0][2]
```

The first version compares the result of `board[0][0]==board[0][1]` (which is a boolean, true or false) with `board[0][2]` which is obviously not what you want.

You can't assume that things that are correct in math also work in C++.

The program would be simpler if you had a consistent indexing scheme for your board. You are asking your user to enter a number from 1 to 9 for the square, but in your program you have a 2D array from 0 to 2. There's three things you could do about this to make you life easier

1) Make the user enter two numbers from 0 to 2 for the square.

2) Change your program so that your board is an array from 1 to 9

3) Write a function that translates what the user enters (1 to 9) into what your board uses (two numbers from 0 to 2).

Any of these options would remove the need for these massive switch statements you are using. Option 3 is probably the best.

Something like this (you could also do something clever using `%` and `/` which would shorten this function a lot, but keep it simple for now).

```
bool translate_coordinates(int choice, int& x, int& y)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        return true;
    case 2:
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        return true;
    case 3:
        x = 0;
        y = 2;
        return true;
    case 4:
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
        return true;
    case 5:
        x = 1;
        y = 1;
        return true;
    case 6:
        x = 1;
        y = 2;
        return true;
    case 7:
        x = 2;
        y = 0;
        return true;
    case 8:
        x = 2;
        y = 1;
        return true;
    case 9:
        x = 2;
        y = 2;
        return true;
    default:
        return false; // invalid choice, let the caller handle this
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes something like this

```
void player_turn()
{
    cout<<"\n\tPlayer1[X] turn:";
    cin>>choice;
    int x, y;
    if (translate_coordinates(choice, x, y))
        board[x][y] = 'X';
    else
        cout << "invalid choice\n";
    display_board();
    //checkwin();
    cout<<"player 2 turn\n";
    cin>>choice;
    if (translate_coordinates(choice, x, y))
        board[x][y] = 'O';
    else
        cout << "invalid choice\n";
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

how about working with this code?

```
    int checkwin()
{
    if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])

        return 1;
    else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])

        return 1;
    else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])

        return 1;
    else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])

        return 1;
    else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])

        return 1;
    else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])

        return 1;
    else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9])

        return 1;
    else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])

        return 1;
    else if (square[1] != '1' && square[2] != '2' && square[3] != '3' 
                    && square[4] != '4' && square[5] != '5' && square[6] != '6' 
                  && square[7] != '7' && square[8] != '8' && square[9] != '9')

        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```